# getContentAsPDF() - Internal server error

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf, getcontentaspdf

I am trying to generate a table of records in pdf and sending it as email attachment from apex by using getContentAsPDF() method .
The method works fine until we are processing more then 12 records. For more then 12 records it's giving `Internal server error`. I am not able to debug that also.
The table of records that I am trying to send :

[image]

The Apex code for it :

```apex
pageRef.getParameters().put('transactionString',listOfTransactions);
    pdfBlobVf = pageRef.getContentAsPDF();
```

I think the issue occurs when we are putting parameters.

Here transactionString is the table data in string serilized form.

Comment: The parameter does need to be a string e.g. CSV values. Your screen shot doesn't show a serialized form - do update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a maximum URL length of 16,384 characters. See Request Size Limits in the [API Request Limits and Allocations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm) documentation. This is the most likely cause for your problem if you're serializing entire records. Try sending just the record Ids and then query those records in the PDF page's controller.

Comment: yeah,It was the issue of url limit.